# Cannot boot windows 10, “bootrec /fixboot” gives “access denied”

Tags: windows-10, boot

My “always on” home desktop today appeared to be totally unresponsive. It was clear that I had only one choice to power reset it. At first it seemed that it booted into my login screen, but again my I did power reset by mistake. From this point on I wasn’t able to boot. It shows *“inaccessible boot device”* blue screen.

Recovery or restore doesn’t work. From cmd prompt I see my C:\ drive and all files seem to be ok, entire `chkdsk` shows that everything is ok with the drive.

`bootrec /FixMbr` works, however `bootrec /fixboot` gives me *“access is denied.”*

`bootrec /scanos` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` both show *“Total identified windows installations: 0”*

I tried to run it all from the UEFI partition by enabling it from `diskpart` but I still get *“access denied”* for `fixboot`, no matter what I tried. There is one suggestion for the *“access denied”* error: to format the UEFI partition and then manually create `EFI\Microsoft\Boot\` in there and retry `bootrec /fixboot` but I find it outlandish to even consider it.

Any suggestions? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 46):

I ran into the same issue, the suggestion from Darko_65 in [Microsoft Answers forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-cant-boot/5b675a98-ac85-46f1-894a-9a8ac016caec) is what worked for me:

```
"bootrec" command sometimes has problems finding proper boot device and windows installation to fix.

Use "bcdboot" command to fix boot (bcdboot requires that partitions are specified explicitly!)

bcdboot C:\windows /s S:

specifies C: as Windows partition, S: as system partition.

Use "diskpart" or "mountvol" commands to map system partition.
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved m̶y̶ ̶l̶i̶f̶e̶  my cloned win10 installation on a new SSD drive.

Comment: Saved my bacon too. Had cloned my SSD to a new bigger one then wiped. Just 'bcdboot C:\windows' fixed it for me.

Comment: Bacons are still being saved for those of us who clone to larger SSDs.

Comment: Worked for me. Simply running `bcdboot C:\windows` without the `/s` part sufficed.

Comment: Worked for Windows 7 x64 in UEFI mode too. If you don't see letter/volume on GPT disk, run `diskpart`, then `select partition X` and and `set id=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`

Comment: Thank you. In my case, my original C: drive in HDD was a logical partition. But during cloning operation, I cloned it to an SSD primary partition. It may be the reason my cloned windows was not booting. I booted into my old windows and used `bcdboot` command after mounting (assigning drive letter from disk management) cloned 'windows' partition and the 'system reserved' partition. It worked. Thank you again.

Comment: I really appreciate the solution, you just saved me hours and hours of time

Answer (score 7):

In the answer given by @aoetalks, copying the BCD files to new mount point didnt worked for me. It always ended up saying source files not found. It could be because my /EFI directory got corrupted.

Anyways, **trying to boot with a Windows 8.1 USB media worked**. 
All the commands, bootrec /fixmbr, /fixboot, /scanos, and /rebuildbcd worked fine and I'm back to my desktop in a few minutes.

It looks like the Windows 10 bootrec has some issues.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked for me too.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is what finally worked for me! I think it has something to do with Windows 10 repair tools assuming a UEFI setup. However my partition uses the legacy MBR BIOS. I used [Rufus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufus_(software)) to create a bootable USB from the [Windows 8.1 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows8) (and set the partition scheme accordingly).

Comment: August 2020 - confirmed this worked for me too. /fixboot failed persistently ("Access denied") on win 10 2004 install media. Worked first time using Win 8.1 install media.

Answer (score 4):

It's been  much easier for me: after 2 weeks (!!) of Windows 10 not booting with UEFI not recognizing my GPT disk anymore, I simply used `diskpart` from an installation DVD/USB:

```
diskpart
list disk
sel disk 0
sel vol 1
attributes volume clear readonly
sel vol 2
attributes partition clear readonly 
sel vol 3
attributes...
```

...worked for me so I could boot into Windows 10 after 2 weeks, WITHOUT reinstalling.

Comment: I've edited this answer to make the commands valid, as `attributes partition...` is not valid syntax and `attributes volume...` is the command that's likely being referred to instead, but I haven't confirmed that the answer works.

Comment: After selecting the EFI volume, and confirming it is active (starred), entering ATTRIBUTES PARTITION CLEAR READONLY gives 'Virtual Disk Service error: The object is not found.'

Answer (score 1):

After installing Windows 10 cumulative update 2021-06 for 20H2 (KB5003637) my laptop didn't boot but displayed "*Operating system not found*" error message. I tried @aoetalks's solution but got `Failure when attempting to copy boot files.` error message.

Apparently my EFI partition got somehow corrupted, since I was able to fix the issue by completely recreating the EFI System Partition with following steps:

1. Boot from Windows 10 USB
2. Select your region and then click Next > Repair Computer > Troubleshoot... > Advanced > Command Prompt
3. Enter recovery key(s) if you have BitLocker enabled
4. At the command prompt enter following commands (instructions found from [NavyLCDR's post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/152232-bcd-corrupted-cannot-boot-windows-10-a-post1861653.html#post1861653)):

```
diskpart
lis vol  <- note which drive letter your Windows partition is assigned
lis dis <- note the disk number of the drive containing your EFI system partition
sel dis # <- replace # with the drive identified above
lis par <- note which partition is the EFI System partition
sel par # <- replace # with the partition number identified above
del par override
cre par EFI
for fs=FAT32 quick
assign letter=s
exit
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI <- note may need to change C: to the drive letter identified above
exit
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions!  After a BIOS update my wife's Windows 10 laptop refused to boot with a BCD error code 0xc0000098 and I was able to use this to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're here with "inaccessible boot device" and nothing else in this thread has helped you, then you're probably trying to boot from an enclosure or usb/nvme drive - you need to do this:

edit the registry `HKLM/SYSTEM/HardwareConfig/{..guid..}` and set `BootDriverFlags = 0x14` (the guid is system specific and you could have multiples if you've booted different systems with the drive, if you're unsure which one you can just edit them all)