# How to remove GRUB and restore the Windows Bootloader?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I am on a Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot machine. Recently, Windows has not been able to install updates (after rebooting, it says couldn't complete updates, reverting changes). Now I want to test whether it'll work with the standard windows bootloader, so I want to remove GRUB and restore the Windows bootloader.

According to diskmgmt.msc → disk 0 → properties → Volumes, the partition style of my disk is **Master Boot Record (MBR)**. My Mainboard has UEFI.

What I have done so far:

- Created a Win10 boot disk
- From Boot disk → troubleshooting tried the option "startup repair", which didn't do anything
- in recovery cmd: `bootrec /fixmbr` → command is run successfully
- in recovery cmd: `bootrec /fixboot`→ acces denied

Then I read in [Cannot boot windows 10, “bootrec /fixboot” gives “access denied”](https://superuser.com/questions/1285268/cannot-boot-windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-gives-access-denied) that `bcdboot C:\Windows` should help in this case, but I'm getting `Failure when attempting to copy boot files` as an error. As an alternative, also the command `bcdboot C:\windows /s S` is given, where `S` is the EFI partition. The problem is that I don't seem to have an EFI partition:

[image]

Here the very left partition, 256gb, belongs to Ubuntu. The System reserved partition is NTFS, so as far as I understand it, this cannot be the EFI partition?. C:\ is my Windows installation. The very right seems to be a recovery partition.

I could try to run `bcdboot C:\windows /s S` with `S` being the System Reserved Partition, but I don't really have a clue what that is doing.

Any hints on how I could solve my problem?

Comment: Before you try: Failure to complete updates has usually nothing to do with the bootloader

Comment: GRUB should be able to boot Windows.

Comment: Hi Basile, thanks for your comment. Yes, my GRUB does boot Windows, it's just the Windows updates that are a problem and I thought it could have something to do with the MBR/GRUB.